# ElasticSearch: Is there any application that enable access management to ElasticSearch?

Tags: authentication, elasticsearch, production, user-management

I'm running an ElasticSearch cluster in development mode and want it to be production ready.

For that, I want to block all the unnecessary ports, one in particular is port 9200.

The problem is that I will not e able to monitor the cluster with HEAD or Marvel plugin.

I've searched around and saw that ElasticSearch recommendation is to put the entire cluster behind an application that manages the access to the cluster.

I saw some solutions (ElasticSearch HTTP basic authentication) which are insufficient for this matter.

Is there any application that can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch actually have a product for this very purpose called Shield. You can find it [here](https://www.elastic.co/products/shield).